# ThreadPoolTaskExecutor blocks feeder thread forever

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm trying to have a single thread loading records (say from a database). This thread feeds records into a thread pool that processes these individual tasks.

I was expecting this code to work, but it prints number until 60 and then stops.

```
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor accountLoaderTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
accountLoaderTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(1);
accountLoaderTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(1);
accountLoaderTaskExecutor.initialize();

ThreadPoolTaskExecutor accountDeletionTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
accountDeletionTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(10);
accountDeletionTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
accountDeletionTaskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(50);
accountDeletionTaskExecutor.initialize();

accountLoaderTaskExecutor.submit(() -> {
    List<Integer> customerAccountIds = getCustomerAccountIds();  // return 1000s integers
    customerAccountIds.forEach(id -> {
        accountDeletionTaskExecutor.submit(() -> {
            try {
                System.out.println(id);
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
    });
});

Thread.currentThread().join();
```

I was expecting the `accountLoaderTaskExecutor` thread to block on `accountDeletionTaskExecutor.submit` but then continue as records are being processed until it exhausts all customerAccountIds.

Answer (score 0):

If that comment "return 1000s integers" means that you have thousands of ids, then the code you have written will queue thousands of tasks to the threadpool and then proceed to `Thread.currentThread().join()` which does absolutely nothing, because joining the current thread to itself is meaningless: you can only join different threads.

Then, I presume you exit the application, and the default behavior is probably to terminate all threadpools on application exit. (I am not sure about that, I am speculating.)

The 60 tasks that you observe getting started probably manage to start while the remaining thousands of tasks are being queued.

To verify that this is what is happening, you can try replacing that call to `join()` with a `Thread.sleep( 1000 )` and see if you observe more tasks being started.

If that is the case, then one approach to solve your problem might be to add proper graceful threadpool shut-down (of the kind that waits for all queued tasks to complete first.)

Comment: note that `accountDeletionTaskExecutor` has a queue capacity of 50 so I don't think we are queueing 1000s of jobs. I've tried to replace `join` with `sleep` but the result is the same, 60 records got processed, then it just hangs

Comment: oh, right, I did not notice the queue size. So, the observed behavior is weird. I will probably delete the answer, or I might modify it if we manage to find a solution by troubleshooting.  So, what happens if you alter the length of the existing `Sleep` in your code?

Comment: Also: I do not remember the exact behavior of threadpoolexecutor but it is possible that any exception thrown by your tasks gets swallowed, which means that any failure in your tasks is a silent failure. So, can you please rearrange your code so that no exception is ever propagated to the threadpoolexecutor?  (Wrap everything in try..catch, and print the stack trace of any exception thrown. Do this for both anonymous task classes)

Comment: I am saying this because even though it might be reasonable to expect that once the queue becomes full, the enqueuing operation will block waiting for the queue to become non-full, rumor has it that what happens instead is that any attempts to queue new tasks once the queue is full are rejected. In java, "rejected" usually means that an exception is thrown, and the way your code is written you would not know.

Comment: Hello kms333, are you still there or did we lose you?